# Method for getting the dynamically updated html page code in webview of an ios application ?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, delegates

I am trying to get the code of the html in a webview of an ios application . I can get the html code when the page is loaded in web view using UIWebView delegate methods. In the app,i have some dynamic contents which are added after clicking a button (html button) in that page.It is done through some javascript or ajax call. But i could not find any delegate methods, to detect the actions and changes in the web view . Could any one suggest me the way for getting the updated html page webview ?

Comment: i dont know exact but try with webview delegate - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType delegate of WebView you may find something if that method is invoking after button click.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access web content in UIWebView from native code. But you can use js, like a userjs in desktop browser. Please consider usage of method [- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:)